# can lights in blender influence image sequence?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, customization

I have a image sequence imported in blender and I want it to be influenced by the lights in blender, not just the shadow but also the amount of light and color of light.

Comment: Absolutely. Just use a regular shader (eg. a principled or diffuse bsdf) allowing the image plane (or sequence on a plane) receive shadows/lights.

Comment: @brockmann thankyou for answering first of all, and shadow is working but when i am putting lights off my image sequence plane is not getting affected or if I am changing the color of light it's not getting affected by this

Comment: If the shadow is working why the light shouldn't? Suggest bump up the intensity or provide a blend file using https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @brockmann I tried uploading it many times but it's not getting uploaded

Comment: Follow the instructions and it will work, not sure what *exactly* you're trying to upload though. Quick test using images as planes add-on, works out of the box using a spot light, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F3Wx.jpg and if that works for a single image it will work for a sequence as well.

Comment: @brockmann thankyou it's now working actually I learned blender from youtube because I wanted to make a movie